# Manually trigger href or onClick in my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm customizing a website that was build by someone else using a WYSIWYG. I'm stuck with an href having javascript in it.

How can I, onClick of this anchor tag, capture the href, change it's value to `#`, preventDefault, and then actually run what was going to originally be ran? I know this is a bit odd, but it's currently causing IE errors and I believe it will fix it.

HTML:

```
<a class="cpMonthNavigation" href="javascript:CP_refreshCalendar(3,1,2012);">&lt;&lt;</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).click({namespace: this}, function (e) {
    var t = e.data.namespace;

    if ($(e.target).is($(".cpMonthNavigation"))) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(e.target).attr("href").replace(/javascript:/i, "");
        // This is where I need to manually run the function that was in the HREF
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that I *cannot* edit the HTML. I'm stuck with it and it's terrible-ness.

I need to preventDefault so that the vendor code *does not* run but still run what's actually in the href. There are multiple things behind the scenes in the vendor code bound to the click of this anchor.

Comment: Why do you want to capture the click and do the same thing?

Comment: Because there is a ton of build in vendor javascript that is tracking *every* click of an anchor tag and firing functions on *every* anchor tag click. I need to stop the vendor javascript (that I can't edit) but still run the javascript that is in the href.

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of jQuery code:

```
$(".cpMonthNavigation").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var expression = $(this).attr("href"); 
    eval(expression);
    $(this).attr("href", "#");
};
```

Comment: @JesseAtkinson misunderstood your question. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I may be making this simpler than needed but to simply run the function, preventing defaults:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.cpMonthNavigation', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myHref = $(this).attr("href");
    myHref = myHref.replace(/javascript:/i, "");
    var myNewFunc = myHref.replace(/javascript:/i, /""/i);
    eval(myNewFunc);
});
```

a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/Vta56/

EDIT: shorter version of above:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.cpMonthNavigation', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    eval($(this).attr("href").replace(/javascript:/i, ""));
});
```

Comment: IF you have other links, just add the class in the `'a.cpMonthNavigation, a.newclass'` part

Comment: note: my above code leaves the original href so that it does not break the function on other clicks - easily added if you want that part to REALLY be `href='#'` (left the above a bit wordy to show each step explicitly)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` to invoke the function. But that is considered as a bad practice in `Javascript Programming`.

The other way i could think of is, define the function inside an object like,

```
var operations = {
    CP_refreshCalendar : function(mm, dd, yyyy){
                              //your code
    }
}
```

Then, from the click event handler, you could do

```
$(document).click({namespace: this}, function (e) {
var t = e.data.namespace;

if ($(e.target).is($(".cpMonthNavigation"))) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var hrefVal = $(e.target).attr("href").replace(/javascript:/i, "");
    var funcName = hrefVal.substring(0, hrefVal.indexOf('(') - 1);
    var args = hrefVal.substring(hrefVal.indexOf('('), hrefVal.index(')') - 1);
    args = args.split(',');
    if(funcName in operations){
         operations[funcName].apply(window, args);
    }

}
}
```

May be i am making this complex. But i will not use `eval`.

I Hope this helps.